# Find a subspace of $R^4$ that contains both V and W.

Tags: vector-spaces

> $V = span \{(1,1,1,1),\,(1,-1,1,-1)\}$ and
>
> $W = 2x + y - z = 0, \,y + z + w = 0 $

Comment: Why not just use $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: **First**, I tried to convert the homogeneous system into a span.

Comment: **Then**, then I found two basis of the space for example (1,-1,1,0) and (-1,-2,0,2)

Comment: And I check if in the union all the vectors are **linearly independent** @erfink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first note, $\mathbb{R}^4 \supset V, W$ so $\mathbb{R}^4$ is certainly "a vector space containing $V$ and $W$." However, the spirit of the question wants us to find something that is potentially a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Taking the coordinates to be, in order, $(w,x,y,z)$, we have that
$$W = span \{ (1,0,1,1), ~ (0,2,1,-1) \} = \{ \vec{w_1}, \vec{w_2} \}.$$

Taking $V= span \{\vec{v_1}, ~\vec{v_2} \}$, we have that the smallest sub-space of $\mathbb{R}^4$ containing $V$ and $W$ is 
$$U = span \{ \vec{v_1}, ~\vec{v_2} , ~\vec{w_1}, \vec{w_2} \}.$$
If we care about knowing how big $U$ actually is, i.e., its dimension, we would perform need to find a basis for $U$. We would do this by identifying a linearly independent subset of our vectors $\{\vec{v_1}, ~\vec{v_2} , ~\vec{w_1}, \vec{w_2} \} \}$ that still provides a spanning set. In this case, we have that they are already linearly independent so 
    $$U = \mathbb{R}^4.$$